# ES6 Import/CommonJS Require Bundle

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, ecmascript-6, node-modules

Is there a way to bundle all common node modules in a custom module? I want to make a few modules to import groups of node modules.

I used to use Wepack's 'ProvidePlugin', which shims (is this the correct word?) modules to be available globally. I don't love global shims because they pollute the global scope, and I don't need all of my "common modules" to be available globally. Instead, I would prefer to be able to group my modules and import groups one at a time (see Example). Any ideas or recommendation would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Example:

```
// react_bundle.js
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import ReactDOM, { render } from 'react-dom'


// dev_bundle.js
import '@babel/register'
import path from 'path'
import logger from 'debug-logger'
import c from 'ansi-colors'


// And then from any js file, I could import one/both of the modules
// to include the variables imported in the bundle
import 'path/to/react_bundle.js'
import 'path/to/dev_bundle.js'
```

Comment: I would argue that you are over abstracting. You won't need ReactDom In all of your React components, but you will need React in all of them. You should just import your dependencies as they are needed.

Comment: @MaxBaldwin I have been using `import { React, Component, ReactDOM, render } from 'react_bundle.js'`, so I don't have to import ReactDOM and render if I don't need it. Is this a good workaround?

Comment: But you're still importing `ReactDom` your just not using it. In `react_bundle.js` `ReactDom` is still being imported and then exported whenever you reference `react_bundle.js`.

Comment: @MaxBaldwin Oh, I had no clue! Thanks for the advice

Comment: You won't be able to tree-shake anything from these bundles. Why would you want to do that any way? It seems like you're trying to do Webpack's job to split packages to physical bundles.